# Symfony circular reference in my services - how to restructure?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I've got two services: `OrderManager` and `CouponManager`.  `OrderManager` has a dependency on `CouponManager`.  This works fine.

I'm trying to add functionality to `CouponManager` which relies on a method in `OrderManager`.  However, I cannot inject `OrderManager` into `CouponManager` without getting a circular reference error.

For example:

OrderManager:

```
public function foo() {
    return $this->couponManager->bar();
}
```

CouponManager:

```
public function fubar() {
    if($this->something()) {
        return $this->orderManager->barfu();
    }
}
```

How should I structure this so each service has access to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject service container and get required service directly from the container only in methods that rely on it.

In the services config:

```
services:
    ...
    arguments: [@service_container]
```

And in the service class:

```
public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

Manager call example:

```
Class OrderManager

...

    public function foo()
    {
        $this->container->get('project.bundle.manager.coupon_manager')->bar();
    }
```

Comment: I thought injecting the service container was considered bad practice?

Comment: Well, it is. Sometimes you cannot do it another way, like in your case. The problem lies in the fact that container just cant construct two objects that rely on each other. So it cannot just call `new OrderManager($couponManager);` because `$couponManager` does not exists, same with calling `new` on `$couponManager`

Comment: You could try to change injection method to calls. So instead of injecting managers via constructor arguments use method calls.

Comment: Yea, that makes sense.  I did try changing to injection method, but I got the same error when it was called.  I think the real solution is to refactor my code so they don't depend on each other in such way.